# php use associative array in class to construct HTML

Tags: php, oop

I want to use a associative array (outcome of a PDO query) in a class, so that I can construct a DIV with some database content. 
How to get the array inside the Class? In the while loop I want to make an object, in the Class of this object I want to construct the HTML.

```
while($data = $stmt->fetch( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC )){ 
    $html = new class;
    echo $html;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your while loop to be able to work about like you've written it, you can write the constructor of the class so that it accepts the data as an argument, then implement the div output in the `__toString` method.

```
class HtmlDivFormatter {
    private $data;
    public function __construct($data) {
        $this->data = $data;
    }
    public function __toString() {
        return '<div>' . $this->data['column_name'] . '</div>';
        // whatever HTML you have in mind
    }
}

while ($data = $stmt->fetch( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC )) { 
    $html = new HtmlDivFormatter($data);
    echo $html;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

see `PDO::FETCH_CLASS` or `PDO::FETCH_INTO`
more info here http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php and this
[PHP PDO fetching into objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12881802/php-pdo-fetching-into-objects)

and some example code:

```
<?php
$sql = 'SELECT firstName, lastName FROM users';

$stmtA = $pdo->query($sql);
$stmtA->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, 'Person');

$objA = $stmtA->fetch();
var_dump($objA);

//first create the object we will fetch into
$objC = new Person;
$objC->firstName = "firstName";
$objC->lastName = "lastName";

$stmtC = $pdo->query($sql);
$stmtC->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_INTO, $objC);

$objC = $stmtC->fetch(); // here objC will be updated
var_dump($objC);


class Person{
    public $firstName;
    public $lastName;
}
```